# Migrate Database GitLab 6.3 to 6.9

Tags: database, migration, gitlab

We have an old GitLab Server that we cant update, so i setup a new one with GitLab 6.9 on it.

I have make an Backup on the old one with

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

How to migrate the old one to the new GitLab Server with 6.9 installed on it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off installing [GitLab 6.3](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/6-3-stable) on the new server (with [gitlab-shell 1.7.9](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/tree/v1.7.9)), perhaps following the [6.2 to 6.3 upgrade guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/6.2-to-6.3.md). Then you can migrate the same version, 6.3 on the old server to 6.3 on the new server, and later upgrade the new server to [7.9.x](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/6.x-or-7.x-to-7.9.md). If you try to migrate from a backup of 6.3 to a new install of 6.9, you're going to run into problems, because there are database migrations at multiple point releases. Finally, when you're up to date on the latest version, you could migrate to the [Omnibus installer](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update.md#upgrading-from-a-non-omnibus-installation-to-an-omnibus-installation).

Related, may I ask why you can't take a backup/snapshot and upgrade the existing server in-place?